# Sencha touch select field is not closing when we clicks the back button in android device

Tags: android, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

i have done application using sencha touch 2. **Back page logic is maintaining through the routes in application.** Back logic is working very nice in both ipad/android device. One issue is causing problem in android device when we clicks the back button in device not closing popup select field popup.In this page i have select field, when clicks the select field it will show select field popup with option **cancel** and **done**, i wont select any option directly i will press the back button in android device. it is not closing popup, but it is going to back previous page but select field popup remains opened not closing. **i need to close bottom select field popup when clicks the back button in android device.** Can any one tell me how to achieve this one. I have attached screen shot of select field popup for more reference.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any code I'm guessing that you've either created an own popup or that you've set usePicker to false on the selectfield.

Why so? Wouldn't set usePicker: true, suffice for your solution?

Anyway, do deal with the problem at hand and with the information you've provided what I would have done is to set a id on your popup (or css class) that enables you to identify it and in any relevant route function hide them if they are visible

```
var popupElement = findYourPopup(); //Ext.getCmp("popup") || ParentEl.query("cssclass") etc.
if (popupElement && !popupElement.isHidden()) {
    popupElement.hide();
}
```

Hope that this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for late reply. As suggested by you, I have set usePicker: true and this doesn't seems to work. Coming to the other approach of hiding the element hides the overlay as expected but disturbs the previous view. I am facing this issue in android it works absolutely fine in ipad/iphone.

Comment: Could you explain how it disturbs the previous view? Maybe I can provide further assistance. What would also help is some code that shows us how you have setup the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also handle hardware back button like this:

```
if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", Ext.bind(onBackKeyDown, this), false);

    function onBackKeyDown(eve) {   
        eve.preventDefault();

        //do something
        alert('back button pressed');

    }
}
```